# jfreechart time series chart with events

Tags: java, swing, charts, graph, jfreechart

I am using jfreechart (specially ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()). Is there a way to signal events like Google Finance charts, see the A, B, C etc on the right and in the chart.

[image: google finance charts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this easily.  One possibility would be to place an `[XYPointerAnnotaion][1]` ([example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartMarkerDemo1.htm)) on your chart, then create the legend on the right separately.  You'd have to manage the mapping between the pointers on the chart and the entries in the legend yourself though.

Comment: yes, I have just implemented this. Using IntervalMarker or ValueMarker works for me. Don't need to put the legend on the right, it's ok inside the chart.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible; see [`org.jfree.chart.event`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/event/package-summary.html) and [`org.jfree.data.general`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/package-summary.html) for chart and data events. Also, check out the [JFreeChart Demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) (Java Web Start) entries under Miscellaneous > Crosshairs.